# Proj4js - no transformation for epsg2056

Tags: proj

I have a script which converts local coordinates to WGS84.
The script works fine if source data and source CS is epsg:21781. The CS for the data has changed now to epsg:2056. When I use epsg:2056 as source the point coordinate is not transformed at all and the transformation output equals transformation input. Here is the script where the transformation takes place:

```
var src = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:21781"); //<-- EPSG:2056 does not transform 
var dst = new Proj4js.Proj("WGS84"); 
var point = new Proj4js.Point(center.lon, center.lat); 
Proj4js.transform(src, dst, point)
```

I don't know anything about Proj4js and I'm just stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

You must just use version that is new enough for having support for EPSG:2056. For example, the development versions from http://www.gisinternals.com/ are built with proj.4 version "proj-4.8" and they know your projection.

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.0dev, released 2015/99/99
```

Check if EPSG:2056 is recognized:

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:2056

PROJ.4 : '+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0
+units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["CH1903+ / LV95",
    GEOGCS["CH1903+",
        DATUM["CH1903+",
            SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
            TOWGS84[674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6150"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4150"]],
    PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.95240555555556],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.439583333333333],
    PARAMETER["azimuth",90],
    PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",2600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1200000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2056"]]
```

The definitions of the new and old seem to be:

```
# CH1903 / LV03
<21781> +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.4,15.1,405.3,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs  <>

# CH1903+ / LV95
<2056> +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

Changes seem to be in false easting and northing and in towgs84 parameters.

If you can't update your Proj.4 you can always define the projection with the proj string instead of the EPSG:code. Thus use this as projection and you will be fine:

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: This is not correct (or better say "not accurate"), you cannot transform from 21781 to/from 2056 like this. Well, you get approximate values with an error of < 1.6m, see [Transformation accuracy](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/knowledge-facts/surveying-geodesy/new-coordinates/transition/accuracy.html). If this is sufficient for your application you can go for it. However, then would be easier and quicker just to calculate `X(LV95) = X(LV03) + 2000000` and  `Y(LV95) = Y(LV03) + 1000000` which gives you the same result.

Comment: For better accuracy with proj4 you would need a grid shift file. Swisstopo has probably not published such.

Comment: Swisstopo provides them, you can download for free from here: https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/geo_software/GIS_info. However, it also took me some time to find them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) project site the tool has only a very limited number of predefined projections. You have to define the projection by yourself. Check the documentation.

For proper (i.e. accurate) transformation you have to download the grid-shift files [CHENYX06_etrs.gsb](http://geodesy.geo.admin.ch/shop/files/chenyx06_etrs_ntv2.zip) and [CHENYX06a.gsb](http://geodesy.geo.admin.ch/shop/files/chenyx06_ntv2.zip) from Swisstopo. Here are the definitions for all combinations:

**Transformation from EPSG:21781 to EPSG:2056 (LV03/CH1903 to LV95/CH1903+)**:

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=CHENYX06a.gsb +units=m +no_defs
   +to +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=@null +units=m +no_defs
```

**Transformation from EPSG:2056 to EPSG:4326 (LV95/CH1903+ to WGS84)**:

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +k_0=1.0 +units=m +no_defs
   +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

**Transformation from EPSG:21781 to EPSG:4326 (LV03/CH1903 to WGS84)**:

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=chenyx06etrs.gsb +no_defs 
   +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Obviously you have to swap the definitions if you have to convert the other way around. I don't know where you have to place the grid-shift files, in Proj4 there is a folder named "share" or you can set an environment variable `PROJ_LIB` where you give the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://spatialreference.org
2. Type in 2056 in the search
3. Click [the link for `EPSG:2056`](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2056/proj4/)
4. Click [`proj4`](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2056/proj4/) on the left

Here is your definition,

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Consider adding that to [`lib/global.js`](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/331592795421ae2f4de026046e6b75a90e5aea90/lib/global.js) or supplying it explicitly in the call to `proj4`

Comment: If you like to make **precise** conversion (i.e. proper datum shift) you cannot use this definition. Using this one gives an error up to 1.6m. Code for CoordinateTransformation is `EPSG:15486` , you can find if **officially** at http://www.epsg-registry.org/  (spatialreference.org is *just* a private non-binding home page)